# Как влияет наречие "больше" на выбор окончания А/У: нет сахара/нет сахару?

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания

Интересное выражение: ***больше нет.***

А как влияет наречие "больше" на выбор окончания ***А/У***? В общем случае выбор А/У зависит от грамматики, значения, стиля.

Значение ***партитивности*** может измениться при добавлении наречия?

Приведем пример (стиль **разговорный**):

*– А сахара/сахару **нет**?*

*– Сахара/сахару **больше нет.** Вчера был.*

Comment: Sharon, все собираюсь ответить на этот вопрос, да руки не доходят. Может быть, если найду время, отвечу вечером.